# Take count of distinct rows in a particular column of key space in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I need to take the count of distinct rows in a particular column '`content_id'`of key space user_rating in `Cassandra`. I've used two queries but got an error as follows:

> SyntaxException: line 1:32 no viable alternative at input ')' (SELECT
>   DISTINCT(COUNT([content_id])...)

The queries I tried are :

```
1.  `cqlsh:recommendation_engine> SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(content_id)) FROM user_rating;`   
2.  `select count (distinct content_id) from user_rating ;`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in CQL - please check the CQL's [SELECT syntax definition](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html).

I would recommend to use something like Spark to do "complex data processing"...